# Show message when radio button selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the following to work without much success

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#shippingOptionRadio-5ed62ea40135a-7dac01c2c834210be865275f0700a45a').click(function()
    {
        alert("Please ensure you have selected the correct option");
    });
});
</script>
```

Using inspect on Chrome, I looked for the ID for the radio button and found shippingOptionRadio-5ed62ea40135a-7dac01c2c834210be865275f0700a45a but even so, when I save the javascript and load the page and click the radio button, no message is displayed.

The code I used to find the ID in inspect was as follows:

```
<input name="shippingOptionIds.5ed62ea40135a" class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox" id="shippingOptionRadio-5ed62ea40135a-7dac01c2c834210be865275f0700a45a" type="radio" value="7dac01c2c834210be865275f0700a45a">
```

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: when you refresh the page make sure the id not change, by looking the id name it seem like some autogenerate id

Comment: The id in your javascript doesn't match the id in the selector.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys and I will try to get a demo, but the hard part of it is that it's on my checkout page and the radio buttons are shipping methods, which are placed there by a third party app... so I am trying to get the ID, and then display a message. @JakeParis - sorry, let me update it with the correct ID... even when I put the correct ID it still doesn't work

Comment: Depending on your use-case you may work with css-selectors like `[id^="shippingOptionRadio"] {}` or with `nth-child()` selector when the option is always at the same spot in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an event (type input not click) to the radio and then add condition if the input.checked === true then show message

```js
// select radio input
const input = document.getElementById('input');

// add event on input
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (input.checked) {
        alert('this is a message!');
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="input">
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see yours works when I run the code snippet, but if I apply it to my own coding it doesn't work, I am guessing it might be the platform I am trying to use it on being BigCommerce 'script manager'

Comment: you will have to replace the ID value that's all like this   >>>    const input = document.getElementById('shippingOptionRadio-5ed62ea40135a-7dac01c2c834210be865275f0700a45a');

Comment: make sure that id value is not duplicated

Comment: <script>
// select radio input
const input = document.getElementById('shippingOptionRadio-5ed62ea40135a-51687c0ecc0b9157decb98355a1a79e6');

// add event on input
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (input.checked) {
        alert('this is a message!');
    }
});
</script>

Comment: The above did not work (ps, I had to use a new id to select the right radio button) but none the less, no message was displayed once script added

Comment: could you provide the whole code that has the issue